# Binding loop detected for property "width" of Image

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Let's assume I have a component like this:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rec1

    Rectangle {
        id: rec
        x:10;y:100; height:100;
        color: 'red'
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }
        Loader {
            id:loader
            width: parent.width
            sourceComponent: comp
        }

    }

    Component {
        id: comp
        Rectangle {
            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                leftMargin: 1           // this line
                right: parent.right
            }
            height:img.height
            Image {
                id: img
                source: '/myimage.png'
                width: parent.width
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the console reports:

> QML Image: Binding loop detected for property "width"

But if I change the comp leftMargin to `leftMargin: 0` (not 1), everything is ok

Is this a bug or some feature I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you made a typo:

```
width:100; height:100;
...
anchors {
    left: parent.left
    right: parent.right
}
```

By doing this you:

1. Explicitly set your rectangles `width` (to `100`).
2. Do explicitly anchoring of left side to parents left side *(if this is only one anchoring operation -- it is Ok)* and then -- do anchoring of right side to parent's right side (so you are implicitly defining your rectangle's `width`).

It is contradiction. Try to solve it (for example, by removing right anchoring) and re-run your application.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it is my fault. Now I make a very similar example to show this problem, any idea about this one?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.5.1 GCC 64x on Linux along with QtQuick 2.3 and can't reproduce problem you mention.

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.5.1 Clang 6.0 on Mac OS X (10.11.2) along with QtQuick 2.5.   The result seems correct, but the console report this error message.  Thanks anyway